# $_GET variable in php

Tags: php, html

```
<?php   
$conn = oci_connect('usr', 'pass', 'host');


$instance_status="command1";
$spacecheck="command2";
$log_apply="command3";
$command=$_GET['name'];
echo $command;
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $command);

--some code--
?>
```

My HTML Page:

```
<html>
<title>Status Check</title>
<body>
<b><a href="oraData.php?name=$spacecheck">Spacecheck</a></b>
<b><a href="oraData.php?name=$log_apply">Log Application Status</a></b>
<b><a href="oraData.php?name=$instance_status">Database Status</a></b>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is my code, I intend to assign to $command, the value from the href variable through $_GET. But, when I test this code, $command is not being assigned the value of the variable from $_GET, rather the name of the variable is simply assigned to $command.

Eg, If I click on this:
Spacecheck
This should assign the VALUE of $spacecheck to $command, which is not happening. $command returns '$spacecheck'

How do I do this variable assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try going the other way around, I mean print from php:

```
<?php
echo '<b><a href="oraData.php?name='.$spacecheck.'">Spacecheck</a></b>';
echo '<b><a href="oraData.php?name='.$log_apply.'">Log Application Status</a></b>';
echo '<b><a href="oraData.php?name='.$instance_status.'">Database Status</a></b>';
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are simply writing $spacecheck. What you need to do is jump inside PHP tags and echo the variable values. Like so:

```
      <a href="oraData.php?name=<? echo $spacecheck ?>">Spacecheck</a>
```

or use the php echo shortcut:

```
      <a href="oraData.php?name=<?= $spacecheck ?>">Spacecheck</a>
```

See the difference?

Good luck.

Comment: +1 but I wouldn't recommend the php echo shortcut. I never liked it.

Comment: I wouldn't either. Just trying to be clear about what's happening :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use PHP open and close tags in order to place PHP code in your HTML page among other things. Try this link:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML actually contains the literal string '$spacecheck' in the URL. $variables are only parsed in sections between  tags, not in plain HTML.

Try this in your HTML file (which should be called .php) instead:

```
<?php

$spacecheck = 'foobar'; // (some dummy values)
$log_apply = 'nope';
$instance_status = 'idle';

print("<html>
<title>Status Check</title>
<body>
<b><a href='oraData.php?name=$spacecheck'>Spacecheck</a></b>
<b><a href='oraData.php?name=$log_apply'>Log Application Status</a></b>
<b><a href='oraData.php?name=$instance_status'>Database Status</a></b>
</body>
</html>");
?>
```